# The old elements of canvas reappears after clearing the canvas using clearRect(...)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Whenever I try to clear the canvas using clearRect(), at first it is cleared. But as soon as I start redrawing the old elements reappear. I even tried

`context.width = context.width`

but nothing seems to be working. The canvas is getting cleared initially but on clicking the clear button, it clears at first, but everything reappears. Please help me in debugging this error. The clearRect method is in the end of the code.

Below is the code

```
<script>
        var canv = document.getElementById('canv'),
            ctx = canv.getContext('2d'),
            rect = [],
            move = false;
        var newRect;
        var startX, startY, mouseX, mouseY;
        var offsetX,offsetY;
        function reOffset(){
            var bound = canv.getBoundingClientRect();
            offsetX = bound.left;
            offsetY = bound.top;        
        }
        reOffset();
        function movement(){
            canv.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
            canv.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
            canv.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove, false);
        }
        function mouseDown(event){

            startX=parseInt(event.clientX-offsetX);
            startY=parseInt(event.clientY-offsetY);
            move = true;

        }
        function mouseUp(event){
            mouseX=parseInt(event.clientX-offsetX);
            mouseY=parseInt(event.clientY-offsetY);
            move = false;
            if(!overlap(newRect)){
                rect.push(newRect);
            }
            make();
            //ctx.fillRect(q.left,q.top,q.right-q.left,q.bottom-q.top);
        }

         function make(){
            for(var i = 0; i < rect.length; i++){
                var q = rect[i];
                ctx.fillStyle = randomColour();
                ctx.fillRect(q.left, q.top, q.right - q.left, q.bottom - q.top);
            }
        }
        function mouseMove(event){

            if(move){
                mouseX=parseInt(event.clientX - offsetX);
                mouseY=parseInt(event.clientY - offsetY);

                newRect = {
                    left : Math.min(startX , mouseX),
                    right : Math.max(startX , mouseX),
                    top : Math.min(startY , mouseY),
                    bottom : Math.max(startY , mouseY),
                }
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canv.width, canv.height);
                ctx.strokeRect(startX, startY, mouseX-startX, mouseY-startY);
            }
        }
        function randomColour() {
            var colour = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                colour.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 256));
            }
            return 'rgb(' + colour.join(',') + ')';
        }

        function overlap(newRect){
            var q1 = newRect;

            //if one rect is completely inside another rect
            var inside = function(rectx, recty){
                return(recty.left >= rectx.left && 
                       recty.right <= rectx.right && 
                       recty.top >= rectx.top &&
                       recty.bottom <= rectx.bottom);
            }

            //if the new rect is overlapping any existing rect
            var isOverlaping = false;
            for(var i = 0; i < rect.length; i++){
                var q2 = rect[i];
                var isIntersecting = !(q1.left > q2.right ||
                                       q1.right < q2.left ||
                                       q1.top > q2.bottom ||
                                       q1.bottom < q2.top);
                var isContain = inside(q2, q1) || inside(q1, q2);
                if(isIntersecting || isContain){
                    isOverlaping=true;
                }
            }
            return(isOverlaping);
        }
        movement();

        //clear the canvas for redrawing

        document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener('click', function () {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canv.width, canv.height);
        }, false);      

    </script>`

<head>
    <title>Simple Paint App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id ="canv" width="1000" height="600" ></canvas>
    <div id="button" style="position: absolute;">
    <input type="button" id="clear" value="Clear">
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm confused about how you want this to work. Do you not want it to draw every rectangle in the `rect` array in your `make` function?

Comment: Yeah, I am trying to draw all the rectangles whenever I try to drag my mouse.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the rect array as well.

Adding this to your clear callback function:

```
document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener('click', function () {
            rect = [];
            console.log(rect);
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canv.width, canv.height);
        }, false);
```

should work, while removing the reset of the rect array (as in your clear callback function), logs the old rectangles as well.

Comment: I did not think of this and I spent whole 2 days on this small problem :p. This worked smoothly. Thank you :)